# Users and user groups are not automatically created when installing packages

Tags: centos, system-administration, server-administration

CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

When installed on other packages, users and groups were always created as needed, for example:

```
[root@cloud ~]# yum install VirtualBox-5.1
```

> Running transaction   Installing :
>   VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.38_122592_el7-1.x86_64
>   1/1
>
> Creating group 'vboxusers'. VM users must be member of that group!

But on this machine, users and groups are not created. And not only when installing this package, but also when installing other packages where users should be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need troubleshoot it. here steps to do for troubleshooting (nginx package "yum install nginx"):

- `rpm -q --scripts nginx`
- "copy" user creating sector e.g. ("`useradd -r -g nginx -s /sbin/nologin -d /var/cache/nginx -c "nginx user"  nginx`")
- try to run it manually and find error if exist

Comment: Thank you!!! Yes, I created the necessary users and groups manually before installing the packages.